# Error Loading A Model in a Custom Magento Module

Tags: magento

Here is the error:

```
Warning: include(Mage/Bitstream/Model/Selfawb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

my full config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Bitstream_Selfawb>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Shipping />
        </depends>
    </Bitstream_Selfawb>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <selfawb>
            <class>Bitstream_Selfawb_Model</class>
        </selfawb>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <selfawb>
            <class>Bitstream_Selfawb_Helper</class>
        </selfawb>
    </helpers>
    <resources>
        <selfawb_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Bitstream_Selfawb</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </selfawb_setup>
        <selfawb_write>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </selfawb_write>
        <selfawb_read>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </selfawb_read>            
    </resources>
</global>

<default>
    <carriers>
        <selfawb>
            <model>bitstream/Selfawb</model>
        </selfawb>
    </carriers>
</default>
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the incorrect class group for your carrier model. If you have "bitstream/Selfawb" as the value for `default/carriers/selfawb`, your class group under `global/models` would need to be "bitstream" instead of "selfawb".

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I don't understand why. I tought that reference should be to module - unique, not to namespace.

Comment: The node under `global/models` is arbitrary - it is a variable of sorts for the `<class>` value that you specify (also called a class prefix). See `Mage::getModel()`, `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getModelInstance()`, `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getModelClassname()`, & `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassname().